# UIBarButtonItem initWithCustom view selector not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uibarbuttonitem

I have a right bar button item created using initWithCustom, which works okay on iOS7 and 7.1. But on iOS 8 the selector not working anymore. code:

```
UIButton *btnReload = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btnReload setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 6, 80, 30)];
[btnReload setTitle:@"RELOAD" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnReload setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnReload.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.f];
[btnReload addTarget:self action:@selector(reloadView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnReload];
```

It seems touches are getting lost somewhere. If I create a custom UIButton class which may work, but I can't find where I did wrong or iOS8 has changed something. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For buttons why you are giving 'UIControlEventValueChanged' it should be UIControlEventTouchUpInside in addTarget method

Comment: good point. thanks. silly me. Actually I made a custom button from UISegmentedControl. According to client I changed custom button to default button but forgot to change the action.